# Структурирование приложения с несколькими .h и .cpp

Tags: структуры, c++

Появилась небольшая сложность при разделении классов на несколько файлов.
В .h указываю класс с прототипами и в соответствующем .cpp инициализирую методы и объекты.
Имеется класс app, который использует все остальные классы, но тем не менее в этих используемых классах нужно обращаться к объектам текущего экземпляра класса app.

Делаю следующим образом: 
в app.h объявил класс с прототипами, в нем есть объявление экземпляров классов
material, control, objects.

Перед этим объявил, как бы не ошибиться в выражении, прототипы классов (чтобы на последлующем этапе .h не инклюдили сами себя через app.h).

```
class material;
class control;
class objects;
```

Другие .h имеют одинаковый характер использования, но в них же мне требуется класс app, поэтому делается инклюд на app.h

В app.cpp инклюдятся все .h, и в нем при инициализации каждого класса я передаю в них ссылку на текущий экземпляр app.

Является ли такой способ оптимальным? Особенно если речь идет о усложнении структуры приложения.

Comment: А что такое
> класс с прототипами
> прототипы классов
?
Это же не javascript.

Comment: имеются в виду прототипы методов, которые есть в классах

Comment: В C++ это называется объявлением методов.

Comment: Объявление - это общее понятие, где указывается тело функции. Прототип - без тела функции

Comment: Нет. Функция с телом - это определение функции. Объявление - это другое. Прототипами методы в C++ никто не называет.

Comment: ну-ну https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прототип_функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Почитайте про [ifdef-guard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) или используйте `#pragma once`, если эта инструкция поддерживается Вашим компилятором.
Это позволяет *не думать* о рекурсивных зависимостях при включении файлов.

2) Файлы .cpp в больших проектах включают в указанном порядке:

- во-первых, [Предварительно откомпилированные заголовки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8). Возможно, Вам пока не нужно;
- соответствующий заголовочный файл (то есть для material.cpp - это material.h);
- заголовочные файлы всех классов, которые используются при реализации.

3) В файлы .h стараются писать как можно меньше `#include`'ов. Желательно обходиться объявлениями, как в вопросе:

```
    class material;
    // ...
```

`#include` *приходится* писать для классов, которые Ваш класс наследует или размещает по значению, а также для классов, которые передаются по значению как аргумент функции. Во всех этих случаях компилятору нужно знать размер объекта. Forward-declaration будет мало.